# Rails add @ symbol on username after Signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a gem to add the @ symbol on username after create the user?

Or this is just a html data on the websites like twitter?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? like maybe `before_create {|record| record.username = "@#{record.username}" unless record.username[0] == '@'}`

Comment: @engineersmnky, nope i forget the callbacks, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always add this to the username as part of a `before_validation` call:

```
class User
  before_validation :add_at_to_username
  def add_at_to_username
    return unless (self.username? and !self.username[0,1] == '@')

    self.username = '@' + self.username 
  end
end
```

Then the rest is just using it in a URL. Keep in mind `@` in URLs can be problematic, it's technically not allowed, and may show up as an ugly `%40`.

Comment: ok, so if in this case to show on url have to srip out the @! ok. thank you

Comment: Yeah, write a `to_param` method for use in the URL that strips out the `@`. You could also have the `@` being implicit and not store it in the database, nor the URL, instead have some kind of username formatter that puts it in automatically, as well as scans documents for the `/@\w+/` pattern and converts those to links. That's what Stack Overflow does.